# Object reference not set to an instance of an object using Xml

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am trying to insert my data to a webservice.

while submitting my submit button on my website.  and i am checking whether there is an error:

```
if (Convert.ToString(strXML) != "1")
{
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML.ToString());
     XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Logic/Errors");
     err = node["Error"].InnerText;
}
```

But now i am getting an error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. 
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where 
it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to 
an instance of an object.
```

can anyone help me ???

Comment: probably the `node` is null - debug your code , step by step... the single node is not found for some reason.

Comment: @Aristos yeah node is getting null value. how can i change that?

Comment: The selected node must exist in the xml... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx

Comment: @Aristos so are you saying to add "Error" tag inside the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that xml contains error node within Logic/Errors.

If not exist, the object reference may occur

Comment: i have corrected the problem by myself. The issue was SElection of xml node i changed the name of xml node .